# Read a file multiple time or read once and use deepcopy on the result?

Tags: python

Assume that I have a file in memory (submitted by a HTTP POST request) and a handler `f` for that file. I need to convert the content of the file into an JSON object and use it multiple time (the content is modified each time), so which of the following 2 approaches is preferable?

1. Read the content of the file multiple times (with the help of `f.seek(0)`) and convert it to a new JSON object every time I need the data.
2. Read the content of the file and convert it to an JSON object once, and use a `deepcopy` of the object every time I need the data.

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Usually I/O in files is less efficient than in memory objects, I would choose the second option BUT if you are going to make A LOT of copy you may have memory trouble (it's not likely to happen with today memory)

Answer (score 1):

By performing a `read` each time, you are performing an I/O operation with your Hard Drive.

In comparison, by using `deepcopy` you are only working with the RAM memory.

Given that RAM memory access is much faster than Hard Drive access, I recommend the `deepcopy` method over the `read` method in terms of speed.

*NOTE: If your JSON object is unmutable (e.g.: a Python string) you don't need to perform deepcopy each time, since you get a new object everytime you perform a change in the original object*

Comment: I assume that the file is completely in the memory, as it's submitted through a HTTP POST request. I can be wrong though.

Comment: Can you convert it into a JSON string? this way you have an unmutable object and can avoid deepcopying each time.

Comment: I need to process the data inside that JSON object, so if I store it as a string I will need to call `json.loads()` every time?

Comment: I guess. In the end, if you want to compare all the approaches, just measure the time taken (things like `timeit`in jupyter notebooks) and select the fastest one.